# How to select item navigation drawer from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to change select item from navigation drawer when click button in a fragment

I'have a MainActivity that have a navigation drawer with 3 item..

When the app initialize, the first item is 
obviously selected...

When click on second item, the second item 
obviously is selected and start a fragment..

This is my code...

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            FragmentExample fragment = new FragmentExample();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The fragment have a button that when clicked should select a specific item..

How can i change select item of navigation drawer ( situated in MainActivity) when click a button in fragment??

Sorry for my english.. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define an interface in your fragment, and have your activity implement that interface. You would then call the interface method when you want to trigger the action.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void doSometing();
}

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof MyInterface) {
        mCallback = (MyInterface) activity;
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity + " must implement MyInterface");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mCallback = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Then you simply call

```
mCallback.doSometing();
```

to call into your activity.

Comment: sorry but I do not understand what I should do exactly .
You would have a practical example of what I'm looking for?
 I am not very experienced in android with callback

Comment: Check this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html